# Get the value from an element targeted by its name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me try to explain my problem. I have a radio button "jform[display]" which allow to display a hidden div "greenRect".
With the following code, it does not work.

```
$("input[name='jform[display]']").on('click', function() {
    if ($("input[name='jform[display]']").val() == 1) {
        greenRect.show();
        alert("Value of the Radio Button="+$("input[name='jform[display]']").val());
        return;
    }
    greenRect.hide();

    //It does not work (always=1)!!!
    alert("Value of the Radio Button="+$("input[name='jform[display]']").val());
});
```

The elements $("input[name='jform[display]']").val() is always == 1

If I modify  $("input[name='jform[display]']").val() to  $(this).val(), it works!

```
$("input[name='jform[display]']").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
        greenRect.show();
        alert("Value of the Radio Button="+$(this).val());
        return;
    }
    greenRect.hide();

    alert("Value of the Radio Button="+$(this).val());
});
```

Why does it work with the option2 and not with the option1. I thought that both were similar.
Here is the code with JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/4zmqzecs/2/

Thank you very much for your help

PS: 
The names of my elements are generated by an API:

```
name=jform[display]
id=jform_test0
id=jform_test1
```

They sound strange but it's difficult to modify. Anyway it souldn't be the origin of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather get the value for checked radio button using `:checked` selector:

```
$("input[name='jform[display]']:checked").val()
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v27w4gt1/)**